# Pandas Dataframe function not calling correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, type-conversion

I have two dataframes where I am converting float values to string as part of a vlookup process. Below are my two dataframe table layouts:

df:

| Item Number | Item Description | Item Class | Item Class Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Diamond | 0001 | Gemstone |
| ABC456 | Sapphire | 0001 | Gemstone |
| DEF000 | Silicon | 0002 | Mineral |

df2:

| Item Class | Item Class Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | Gemstone |
| 0002 | Mineral |

I was able to get the Item Class values formatted correctly by doing the following (values were imported as float and had some NaNs):

```
df['Item Class']=df['Item Class'].fillna(value=0,inplace=False)
df['Item Class']=df['Item Class'].astype(int,copy=True,errors='raise')
df['Item Class']=df['Item Class'].astype(str,copy=True,errors='raise')
df['Item Class']=df['Item Class'].apply('{:0>4}'.format)

df2['Item Class']=df2['Item Class'].fillna(value=0,inplace=False)
df2['Item Class']=df2['Item Class'].astype(int,copy=True,errors='raise')
df2['Item Class']=df2['Item Class'].astype(str,copy=True,errors='raise')
df2['Item Class']=df2['Item Class'].apply('{:0>4}'.format)
```

I tried to create a function to condense this:

```
 def float_to_str(df_column):
     df_column=df_column.fillna(value=0,inplace=False)
     df_column=df_column.astype(int,copy=True,errors='raise')
     df_column=df_column.astype(str,copy=True,errors='raise')
     df_column=df_column.apply('{:0>4}'.format)
```

But when I call the function with

```
float_to_str(df['Item Class'])
```

or

```
float_to_str(df2['Item Class'])
```

instead of formatting the Item Class values, the values are not converted, and I either get the error message `ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`, or the df2 values are left as `float`, indicating in both cases the function didn't call correctly. How can I have this function call correctly to condense this code?

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Here's the output from my interpreter (trying to make it look clean):

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [130], in <cell line: 42>()
     39 df2['Item Class']=df2['Item Class'].apply('{:0>4}'.format)
     40 # float_to_str(df2['Item Class'])
---> 42 df=pd.merge(df,df2,how='left',left_on='Item Class',right_on='Item Class')

The arrow points to the df=pd.merge line in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this, since you're creating a new series rather than mutating the existing series in-place:

```
 def float_to_str(df_column):
     df_column=df_column.fillna(value=0,inplace=False)
     df_column=df_column.astype(int,copy=True,errors='raise')
     df_column=df_column.astype(str,copy=True,errors='raise')
     df_column=df_column.apply('{:0>4}'.format)
     return df_column

df['Item Class'] = float_to_str(df['Item Class'])
df2['Item Class'] = float_to_str(df2['Item Class'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the df_column=... assignments do not propagate back to the DataFrame

The way to do this as a function is:

```
def float_to_str(df, colname):
    df[colname].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
    df[colname] = df[colname].astype(int, copy=True, errors='raise')
    df[colname] = df[colname].astype(str, copy=True, errors='raise')
    df[colname] = df[colname].apply('{:0>4}'.format)
```

and to test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Item Number': ['ABC123', 'ABC456', 'DEF000', 'HAL987'],
        'Item Description': ['Diamond', 'Sapphire', 'Silicon', 'Jade'],
        'Item Class': [1, 1, 2, numpy.nan],
        'Item Class Description': ['Gemstone', 'Gemstone', 'Mineral', 'Mineral']
    })
print(df)
```

Gives this:

| # | Item Number | Item Description | Item Class | Item Class Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC123 | Diamond | 1.0 | Gemstone |
| 1 | ABC456 | Sapphire | 1.0 | Gemstone |
| 2 | DEF000 | Silicon | 2.0 | Mineral |
| 3 | HAL987 | Jade | NaN | Mineral |

I added the Nan row just to make sure.
so then this generates the results below:

```
float_to_str(df, 'Item Class')
print(df)
```

| # | Item Number | Item Description | Item Class | Item Class Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC123 | Diamond | 0001 | Gemstone |
| 1 | ABC456 | Sapphire | 0001 | Gemstone |
| 2 | DEF000 | Silicon | 0002 | Mineral |
| 3 | HAL987 | Jade | 0000 | Mineral |